# "Sit in the back." vs "Sit at the back." - differences between American and British usage

Tags: american-english, british-english

As a British English speaker, I was reading a manuscript written by an American English speaker and came across a sentence in the form:

> "She had long hair and so had to sit in the back [of the animal that
>   the group were riding]"

As a British English speaker, I'd never use the phrase "sit in" to describe anything other than a person inside a vehicle or object. So I ended up with the comical image of a young lady sitting inside a riding animal, complete with doors and wheels.

I suggested that the sentence should have been:

> "She had long hair and so had to sit at the back [of the group/of the animal that the group were riding]."

On reading this, my friend commented that she'd never use the phrase `"at the back"` and that the construction didn't even feel grammatical to her. I was very surprised to hear that, since the phrase `"sat at the back [of a lecture theatre perhaps]"` is an utterly standard phrasing in my idiolect.

We were wondering if this is a common difference between American English and British English, since our responses were so different.

Comment: Any sub-part of the back of a rideable animal is really too small and insufficiently "enclosed" to be referenced as a metaphorical ***container*** using the preposition ***in***. Use ***on*** for the horse context. For something like a lecture hall, it's largely a stylistic choice whether to use ***in*** or ***at***, but for smaller and more obviously enclosed spaces (a car, for example), ***in*** is far more likely. I think AmE is more likely to discard the article in, say, *At the cinema, we always like to sit in back* (where BrE would use *sit in **the** back*).

Comment: for clarification, the group of people were riding an undead pterosaur. It's just about large enough that it could theoretically contain a person.

Comment: I can't help noticing that you've used metaphoric ***contain*** in that comment. Arguably ***hold*** or ***support*** would be more appropriate there, but if "container" metaphors work for you in the "pterosaur's back" context then I'm not clear why you have doubts about using ***in*** in the first place.

Comment: it's not that it works for me, so much as it works for the writer when it doesn't work for me. I'm trying to understand if it's just a difference in our native englishes or if it's something else. I can't well disregard her version, she has a reason to believe it correct.

Comment: also, I wanted an excuse to say undead pterosaur. It's a wonderful phrase.

Comment: I fished out charts to show the general picture, but humans and pterosaurs (whether live, dead, or zombified! :) have never coexisted, so there probably won't be any "prior usages" we can refer to.

Comment: I think I'd use *in the back* if I think of *back* as a place (analogous to *in the boot*, or *in the driver's seat*), and *at the back* if I think of *back* as a position (analogous to *at the front*, *at the side*).

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+round+back%2Ccome+round+the+back&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccome%20round%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20round%20the%20back%3B%2Cc0) a chart supporting my earlier assertion that AmE is more likely to discard the article in contexts like *Come round back* (invitation to a visitor to go round/through the house into the back yard/garden). That "article-less" version accounts for about 25% of all AmE instances, but it's too rare to even show on the chart if you switch to the BrE corpus.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The last sentence in your first comment is incorrect: in BrE we would use *sit **at the** back*. Which is kinda the whole thrust of the OP's question!

Comment: @AndyT: I've just searched for the word ***the*** on this page, to make it easier for me to see all highlighted instances of it in OP's question. Apart from revealing a typo *(I ended up with **the the** comical image)*, I can't see anything to suggest OP was even *aware* of the US/UK split re article usage here. But I would just say I think it might be a bit ott to say discarding it is actually "incorrect" in BrE. I use it myself sometimes, and I don't see it as being *that* unusual (but it's still a "minority" usage, even in AmE).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You seem to have misunderstood me, probably due to my bolding "the" as well as "at". I was commenting that you'd used **in**, when in BrE **at** is far more usual. As covered in the question and your answer.

Comment: @AndyT: oic. Well, in that case I'd have to strengthen my position as regards *bit ott to say ... it is actually "incorrect"*. Consider an open-topped miniature railway (at the seaside, for example). The driver (squatting on top of the engine, perhaps) could validly say *Adults should sit **in** the back* (rather than ***on***) so long as the position being referenced could reasonably be seen as a *containing* (rather than *supporting*) location. A pterosaur's back might feasibly be thought of in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how it relates to preferred usage in any *specific* context, but increasingly for the general case, ***in*** occurs far more often in [American English...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20back%20of%20the%2Cat%20the%20back%20of%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20back%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20back%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...where as you can see, ***in*** and ***at*** have reached near-parity. In contrast, [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20back%20of%20the%2Cat%20the%20back%20of%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20back%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20back%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0) continues to significantly favour ***at***...

[image]